# What are some of the docker container settings for running a single instance of ArangoDB?

Tags: docker, go, arangodb, testcontainers

I'm quite new to ArangoDB and I have a requirement to spin off a docker container for ArangoDB, while executing a GO code. The limitation is that the module that enables the spin-off (testcontainers) takes in some parameters for the env settings of the docker container, maybe for the optimal utilisation of resources (For Ex. 1gb for JVM in the case of "ES_JAVA_OPTS" to spin off an Elasticsearch container).

Please let me know what these env settings could be for an Arango docker container (possibly standalone image instead of a cluster one), and how to go about setting them optimally for the spin off to actually happen at run time.

Comment: How would you run the container using the Docker CLI? You can just replicate it with Testcontainers,

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your use case using [testcontainers-go](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go). Here you have an snippet bootstrapping the runtime dependencies for your app programatically next to the tests, which imho is closer to the developer than externalizing it to a call to docker-compose, possibly called in a Makefile or similar.

You would need to add your own app container to the game ;)

```golang
package arangodb

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go"
    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/wait"
)

func TestArangoDB(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    networkName := "backend"

    newNetwork, err := testcontainers.GenericNetwork(ctx, testcontainers.GenericNetworkRequest{
        NetworkRequest: testcontainers.NetworkRequest{
            Name:           networkName,
            CheckDuplicate: true,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        require.NoError(t, newNetwork.Remove(ctx))
    })

    arangodb, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            Image: "arangodb/arangodb:latest",
            Env: map[string]string{
                "ARANGODB_USERNAME":    "myuser",
                "ARANGODB_PASSWORD":    "mypassword",
                "ARANGODB_DBNAME":      "graphdb",
                "ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD": "myrootpassword",
            },
            Networks: []string{networkName},
            Resources: container.Resources{
                Memory: 2048 * 1024 * 1024, // 2048 MB
            },
            WaitingFor: wait.ForLog("is ready for business"),
            Mounts: testcontainers.ContainerMounts{
                testcontainers.BindMount("/my/database/copy/for/arango/data", "/var/lib/arangodb3"),
            },
        },
        Started: true,
    })
    require.NoError(t, err)
    defer arangodb.Terminate(ctx)

    redis, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            Image:    "redis:alpine",
            Networks: []string{networkName},
        },
        Started: true,
    })
    require.NoError(t, err)
    defer redis.Terminate(ctx)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use docker compose and setup different containers for running Arango and another one for running the GO code. That way you can have different env settings for each of them. Below you can see a sample docker-compose.yml file that has Arano, GO and redis. I am adding Redis to show you that you can add even more services there if needed

```
version: '3.9'

# Define services
services:

  arangodb:
      image: arangodb/arangodb:latest
      ports:      
        - 8529:8529
      volumes:
        - /my/database/copy/for/arango/data:/var/lib/arangodb3
      environment:
        - ARANGODB_USERNAME=myuser
        - ARANGODB_PASSWORD=mypassword
        - ARANGODB_DBNAME=graphdb
        - ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword
      container_name: "arango_docker_compose"
      mem_limit: 2048m
      networks:
      - backend

   # Golang Service
  app:
    # Building the docker image for the service based on a Dockerfile of your choice
    build:
      context: . # Use an image built from the specified dockerfile in the current directory.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine, if needed
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: 
      - redis # This service depends on redis and arangodb. Start them first.
      - arangodb
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      - REDIS_URL: redis:6379    
      - ARANGO_PORT: 8529
    networks: # Networks to join (Services on the same network can communicate with each other using their name)
      - backend

  # Redis Service   
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine" # Use a public Redis image to build the redis service    
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
```

For more information about the parameters allowed on ArangoDB docker image please see [ArangoDB docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/arangodb/arangodb)

A sample Dockerfile for GO container can be found at [here](https://github.com/callicoder/go-docker-compose/blob/master/Dockerfile). Please bare in mind that these files are mere samples and you will need to add/replace your required configuration on them. As you want to use `testcontainers` you can also use the Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/helloworld/blob/main/Dockerfile)

Please let me know whether that helps

Thank you!

Comment: The thing with compose, which works really well, is that you have to move from your code to a separate terminal to run it, or maintain code to manage the life cycle of the compose file from your code. Adding containers with Testcontainers in your code allows you to enable the "Clone & Run" experience, as you don't need the tribal knowledge to run the dependencies. With Testcontainers you can simply run your tests with go test, and the dependencies will be there for you.